# Menu Jquery but no work me

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I create simple code for show div when mouse over one link and create simple menu head , the idea it´s when go over the link show me one div and before i can go over this div and select i want over it , but actually i can´t select nothing because if i no over the link the div hide all time

My code it´s this :

```
<style>
#menu_content_head
{
top:125px;
position:absolute;
width:200px;
min-height:100px;
height:auto;
border:1px solid #000000;
background-color:green;
}
</style>


<script>
function menu_head(id)
{

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#h1").hover(function () {
$(".head_m_1").show( "slide", {direction: "up" }, 2000 );
});

$("#h1").mouseout(function () {

$(".head_m_1").hide( "slide", {direction: "up" }, 2000 );
});


});


}
</script>


<div id="web_header_menu_boton">
<a href="#" onmouseover="menu_head('head_m_1');" id="h1">Menu 1</a>
</div>


<div id="menu_content_head" style="display:none;" class="head_m_1">Content 1</div>
```

[JS Fiddle reproduction of posted-code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZYPW7/).

THE PROBLEMS :

1 ) The animation repit more of 1 time , i don´t know why ..... i use stop() , but no work me
2 ) When i go over the link , in first moment no show me the effect of show div , i need go over the link other time for works 
3 ) When i go out over the link the div hide content and i can´t select nothing into the div show

3 things that i need fix , i try but i don´t know how i can do this , and no need nothing more of this , no need complex menu or plugins

Thank´s for the help , Regards !!!

Comment: Why is your `$(document).ready()` *inside* your function?

Comment: why did you put the document ready function inside the menu_head function?

Comment: Y try no put this and happend the same thing ..... i don´t know the most improtant for me it´s get the simple effect of show , hide and select content over the div show , Thank´s !

Comment: Do not mind please. But it is very important to improve your writing skill. It is my one of rare experiences on stackoverflow to not be able to understand and rephrase a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery tooltip that acts like dropdown menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425841/jquery-tooltip-that-acts-like-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYPW7/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#h1").hover(function() {
        $(".head_m_1").show(2000);
    });

    $("#h1").mouseout(function() {

        $(".head_m_1").hide(2000);
    });
});
```

First, you don't need the mouseover handler in the HTML or the menu_head function at all. Second, no overload of `.show()` or `hide()` take those arguments. Check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Perhaps you are looking for [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and it's partner, `.slideDown`?

Comment: Yes but how i can use for example for no one menu i need use in more links by this i use or create function , and by other side i try show the div on mouse over the link but need stay this div for show other links into and before select ..... hide the div which until show ..... and yes i see the function you comment here , but for show the most simple i put only show , etc , basically i want show from link the div and can select other contents into this div and play with hide and show , Thank´s !

Comment: @GerardoGuzmánMiro: Honestly, it's really hard to understand exactly what you are asking for. I *think* you want multiple divs that will open other divs (i.e. a menu effect) and you want the contents of those divs that appear to stay visible. Is that anywhere near correct?